# Change height on TelerikMVC Grid Control

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

Does anybody know a way for changing the height of a Telerik Extensions for MVC Grid? Other than overriding the style manually using

```
div#MyGrid .t-grid-content {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

I'd like to controll that on the grid itself, not on the stylesheet. Telerik samples and documentation say nothing about it and it seems it's [not supported](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/how-to-style-height-as-a-percentage.aspx)

Have anybody faced (and solved) the same issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the height of the grid using the Scrollable method.

Using an int32 representing pixels:

```
.Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(500))
```

Using a string:

```
.Scrolling(scrolling => scrolling.Height("20em"))
```